# How to automount a unit when i click on an executable shortcut to that unit

Tags: 11.04, mount

I use Teamspeak everyday but the teamspeak files are on another partition that i have to load manually before running teamspeak from the Desktop shortcut. Without obviously loading the partition with fstab, how can i load the partition (auto mount it) when i click on the link to teamspeak. For example, i click on the teamspeak shortcut, this checks that the shortcut points to a not mounted partition, it loads the partition and then executes the program.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script for it. Now I won't claim to be a pro scripter (too lazy), but here's an example of what you could do:

> gksu mount /dev/insertpartitionnamehere && exec teamspeak

Comment: i got to say that is one smart script hehe. Thanks Roland.